# How to convert date column to into three columns of date, month and year format in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to convert the given date column into date, month and year format. Initially, there are 2 columns after conversion it would be 4 colums like

```
Country|Date|Month|Year
```

The given data frame is of the type

```
test=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2014,1,1','2014,4,17'],'Country':['Denmark','Australia']})
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2014,1,1','2014,4,17']})
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y,%m,%d")

# If you want to save other datetime attributes as their own columns
# just pull them out assign them to their own columns
# df["Month"] = df["Date"].dt.month 
# df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
```